# Sort the Pictures in Datalist Control

Tags: vb.net, datalist

I Have a Datalist Control and Reading the pictures from folder and showing them in lightbox from Datalist i am also reading data and time from those pictures.Ist thing is that the datalist is not reading the Date picture taken from the attributes and second is that pictures are not being sorted in desc order of date picture taken.Please anyone tell me how can i complete these taskes.
My data list code is here

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="23%" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="0" Height="270px" HorizontalAlign="Center">

<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Image Width="200px" height="200px" ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Name", "~/MMS/1 Box/{0}") %>' runat="server" />
<br />

<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]" title='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LastWriteTime", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd   hh:mm:ss}") %>'
 Text="Zoom" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("Name", "~/MMS/1 Box/{0}") %>' runat="server"/>
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle BorderColor="Silver" BorderStyle="Dotted" BorderWidth="1px" HorizontalAlign="Center"

VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
</asp:DataList>
```

and to read the Images from folder my vb.net code is here

```
Sub loadimage()
        Dim sdir As New DirectoryInfo(MapPath("~/MMS/1 Box"))

        Dim file As FileInfo() = sdir.GetFiles()
        Dim list As New ArrayList()

        For Each file2 As FileInfo In file
            If file2.Extension = ".jpg" OrElse file2.Extension = ".gif" OrElse file2.Extension = ".bmp" Then

                list.Add(file2)

            End If

        Next

        DataList1.DataSource = list

        DataList1.DataBind()


    End Sub
```

Anyone tell me what change should i have to make in code so that my both requirements will be completed as well

Comment: anyone please answer to the question

Comment: Where are you sorting the list items?

Comment: In Datalist Accordingly as in my code the pictures are reading from folder

Answer (score 0):

Use IComparable to sort your list based on time creation time or whatever attribute you want to sort it.

Here is a link which would help you implement this: http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/sortarraylistofobjects.html

Comment: I dnt Understand this method please tell me according to my code please